# C# - Querying XML and Populating a Multi Dimensional Object

Tags: c#, xml

I need to be able to query an xml document such that I can populate an object with data that corresponds to its year and date. The XML will vary from time to time and if a value was not reported for a data point for that year/month then it is simply absent from the mark up. I would still like to populate my object for that month but insert a 0 for it.

For example if an xml contains values for 2015 and months 1,2,4 in adition to the year 2016 months 3,4,5,6 I would need an object that can handle this variability and its multiple dimensions. I need something like `[[Year:2015, Months:[1,2,4]],[Year:2016, Months: [3,4,5,6]]]`

I suppose my question is really two parts.

1) what is the best way to store data that can vary so much. Collection? List? Key Value Pair? Multi Dimensional Array? (I switch around from python and JavaScript a lot so I may have wrong terminology)

2) how to query xml and to populate such an object.

**OBJECT**

```
public class obj1 
{
    public string[] years { get; set; }
    public string[] months { get; set; }


}
```

**XML**

```
<PRODUCTION_SET>
   <ENTITY>
       <METADATA>
       .
       .
       </METADATA>
       <HEADER>
       .
       .
       </HEADER>
       <PRODUCTION>
           <YEAR NUMBER = "2015">
               <MONTH NUMBER = "1">
                   <DATA1></DATA1>
                   <DATA2></DATA2>
               </MONTH>
               <MONTH NUMBER = "2">
                   <DATA1></DATA1>
                   <DATA2></DATA2>
               </MONTH>
               .
               . 
               . 
           </YEAR>
           <YEAR NUMBER = "2016">
               <MONTH NUMBER = "1">
                   <DATA1></DATA1>
                   <DATA2></DATA2>
               </MONTH>
               <MONTH NUMBER = "2">
                   <DATA1></DATA1>
                   <DATA2></DATA2>
               </MONTH>
               .
               . 
               . 
           </YEAR>
        </PRODUCTION>
    <ENTITY>
</PRODUCTION_SET>
```

**QUERY**

```
    public IEnumerable<obj1> queryProduction()
    {
         return this.doc.Root.Elements("PRODUCING_ENTITY").Select(pe => new obj1{
            foreach(var year in pe.Element("PRODUCTION").Elements("YEAR") .....?){
            // do stuff to assign months to current year in object.
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were looking for flexibility and scalability, I would create specific classes for Month and Year objects. Besides, .NET makes XML serializing and deserializing XML an easier task, so not a great amount of code is required. If you are looking for performance, maybe a simpler object data type would be a better option.

So, I would create something like this (this might be full of syntax errors, did it on notepad, sorry):

```
[Serializable()]
public class Production
{
    public Year[] Years {get;set;}
}

[Serializable()]
public class Year
{
    public int YearNumber {get;set;}

    public int SomeData1 {get;set;}

    public int SomeData2 {get;set;}

    public Month[] Months {get;set;}
}

[Serializable()]
public class Month
{
    public int MonthNumber {get;set;}

    public int SomeData1 {get;set;}

    public int SomeData2 {get;set}

    public Month()
    {
        // Default value for data - Although integer variables already default to 0,
        // so there is no need to do this explicitly
        this.SomeData1 = 0
        this.SomeData2 = 0
    }
}
```

Two remarks:

1) I would advise you to handle your month and year numbers as a numeric type, in order to be able to use it more easely from your code.

2) I use the [Serializable()] attribute to mark my class as serializable, so then you should use a [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) object to achieve the querying and population of the object. Deserialization would look like something like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Production), new XmlRootAttribute ("Production"));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
Production prod = (Production) serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

Take a look at [XML serialization with .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx) in general, you can make it as easy or as sophisticated as you want, it is a very powerful tool that the .NET framework provides.

Comment: I find this fascinating and am testing with it. Can you explain the `public Month() Months {get;set;}` and `public Year() Years {get;set;}`

Comment: Updated the post, I did a typo ;) I meant to declare properties that are respectively an array of Month objects and an array of Year objects. .NET deserialization should handle array serialization pretty well, take a look here for further help --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still working through this but I am liking it. Thank you for showing me the way! Learned something new.

Comment: Glad it helped :) go for it!!

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication33
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            obj1.obj1s = doc.Descendants("YEAR").Select(x => new obj1
            {
                year = (int)x.Attribute("NUMBER"),
                month = (int)x.Element("MONTH").Attribute("NUMBER")
            }).ToList();

        }

    }
    public class obj1
    {
        public static List<obj1> obj1s = new List<obj1>();
        public int year { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store whole thing as List where Object is user defined type (class) which will have two properties i.e. Year and Months. Year property can be of type int while Months will be List. So essentially it will look like as below:

```
public class YearStats
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public IList<int> Months { get; set; }

    public YearStats()
    {
        Months = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

If you need to store data for days as well then you can change type of Months to IList. Again here object will be class whose definition will be on same lines as that of YearStats.

And you can load data using following code snippet.

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("Test.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> yearList =
                                 from el in doc.Elements("YEAR")
                                select el;
        List<YearStat> yearData = new List<YearStat>();

        foreach (XElement yearEle in yearList)
        {
            YearStat year = new YearStat();

            year.Year = int.Parse((string)yearEle.Attribute("NUMBER"));

            var monthList = yearEle.Elements("Month");

            List<int> monthData = new List<int>();

            foreach(XElement monthEle in monthList)
            {
                monthData.Add(int.Parse((string)monthEle.Attribute("NUMBER")));
            }

            year.Months = monthData;

            yearData.Add(year);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like many of us are thinking of similar solutions...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace QueryingXML_41271961
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string thePath = @"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\QueryingXML_41271961\QueryingXML_41271961\sample.xml";

            XDocument theXMLDoc = XDocument.Load(thePath);
            List<XElement> theYears = theXMLDoc.Descendants("PRODUCTION").Elements("YEAR").ToList();
            List<InfoHolder> mylist = new List<InfoHolder>();

            foreach (XElement yearInXML in theYears)
            {
                InfoHolder ih = new InfoHolder();
                ih.years = yearInXML.Attribute("NUMBER").Value;

                foreach (XElement monthsInYear in yearInXML.Elements("MONTH"))
                {
                    if (ih.months == null)
                    {
                        ih.months = monthsInYear.Attribute("NUMBER").Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ih.months += "," + monthsInYear.Attribute("NUMBER").Value;
                    }
                }
                mylist.Add(ih);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    public class InfoHolder
    {
        public string years { get; set; }
        public string months { get; set; }
    }
}
```